# Splitting string in column in table which has multiple values into separate rows

Tags: sql, split

Using SQL server management studio 2016, I have a column where if there is a delimiter `;` then I need to split the values into two separate rows.

I can split the values for a single value but it doesn't work when I need to do this for a column in a table

Table values:

```
Server Environment
S23     PROD, DEV
S24     PROD
```

Query One:

```
 SELECT [server], STRING_SPLIT([Environment]), ';')
   FROM [[dbo].[serverstable]
```

Query Two:

```
ECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400), @Environment NVARCHAR(400)

SET @tags = (SELECT [Environment] FROM [dbo].[Servers] WHERE [SERVER] = 'S23')
SET @Environment = (SELECT [Environment] FROM [dbo].[Servers])

BEGIN

IF @Environment LIKE '%;%'

SELECT value

FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ';')

IF  @Environment NOT LIKE '%;%'

SELECT @Environment

END
```

Error for query one:

> 'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Error for query two:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Expected results

```
Server Environment
S23     PROD
S23     DEV
S24     PROD
```

Comment: SSMS version is irrelevant. you want to know what the server version is (use `select @@version` to find out). String_split was introduced in 2016 and requires a compatibility level of 130 or higher.

Comment: You say your values are semi-colon (`;`) delimited, but your example says otherwise (`'PROD, DEV'` is comma (`,`) delimited). Really, however, you should be fixing your design; storing delimited data in your database is just one "simple" way of slowing it down.

Comment: I can use SSMS 2017 to connect to SQL Server 2000. Does not mean I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: ok please ignore the SSMS version, and yes I meant to write 'prod; dev'. Please can you focus on helping me solve the issue it would be appreciated. I am unable to change the approach to storing as I am not the decision maker on this so need to work through the existing data

Comment: We need to know your SQL Server version to start then, @RyanB .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split_string` return value is a `table`, so you can't use it as column

```
SELECT [server], STRING_SPLIT([Environment]), ';')
FROM [[dbo].[serverstable]
```

Thus: it will give you this error:

[image]

What you need is: `cross join` the `t1.environment` values

```
 SELECT [server], t2.value
 FROM [dbo].[serverstable] t1
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.[Environment], ';') t2
```

Comment: That answer is correct, assuming the server version is actually 2016 or higher, and the database's compatibility level is 130 or higher. However, the question seems to imply otherwise, as the OP is reporting an error "'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.".

Comment: @ZoharPeled, if you use string_split as column it will give you `'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`, please give it a try.

Comment: I stand corrected. Upvoted your answer as it seems you are correct.